# Print PHP image

Tags: php, html, image

I want to print this PHP image http://www.putlocker.com/include/captcha.php?_CAPTCHA&t=0.94178300+1332596358 in my PHP script.

Source (is the captcha image): http://www.putlocker.com/authenticate.php?login

What can I do?

Comment: @ZombieHunter I can't use the common methods (ie: file_get_contents, cURL), so I was hoping that you could help me.

Comment: Why not? If so, put this information into the question. cURL is extremely powerful, I'm pretty sure this can be done using cURL.

Comment: `echo '<img src="http://pulocker.com/authenticate?login" />';`?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to let you access that image other than by viewing it on the webpage. The captach image contains a time parameter (&t=sometime). It also throws a 500 server error so unless you're willing to work this out then I'd probably just leave it alone.